# "lead to deadlock" error when doing a certain activity multiple times

Tags: android, performance, android-account

I'm testing my app on a device and after doing a certain activity 5 or 6 times, the app crashes with error: `java.lang.IllegalStateException: calling this from your main thread can lead to deadlock`

The activity is simple: User puts in a task and clicks save. At this time, I get their username and authtoken and make a POST request to my server.  I wonder if my app is crashing because each time I am getting the username and authtoken.

The crash is happening in the below code at line `new CreateTask`.

```
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem menuItem) {
    if (menuItem.getTitle().toString().equalsIgnoreCase("save")) {
        new CreateTask(this,taskName.getText().toString(), getMyAccount().getUsername(), getMyAccount().getAuthToken()).execute();
        return true;
    }
return true
}
```

The code for `getMyAccount()` looks like this:

```
private MyAccount getMyAccount() {
    MyAccount myAccount = new MyAccount(getApplicationContext());
    return myAccount;
}
```

And finally the class `MyAccount` looks like below:

```
public class MyAccount {
    private static final String TAG = "MyAccount";
    private final Account account;
    private final AccountManager manager;
    private final Context context;
    public MyAccount(final Context context) {
        this.context = context;
        final Account[] accounts = AccountManager.get(context).getAccountsByType("com.myapp");
        account = accounts.length > 0 ? accounts[0] : null;
        manager = AccountManager.get(context);
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return account!=null? manager.getPassword(account): null;
    }

    public String getUsername() {
        return account!=null? account.name: null;
    }

    public String getAuthToken() {
        if (account != null) {
            AccountManagerFuture<Bundle> future = manager.getAuthToken(account,"com.myapp", false, null, null);
            try {
                Bundle result = future.getResult();
                return result != null ? result.getString(KEY_AUTHTOKEN) : null;
            } catch (AccountsException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Auth token lookup failed", e);
                return null;
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Auth token lookup failed", e);
                return null;
            }
        }
        else
            return null;
    }
}
```

**Question**

Is this not a best practice? Is my app crashing because I keep getting the `account` and `authtoken` repeatedly? What is a way to avoid this?

Comment: The problem was not in calling `manager.getAuthToken` on UI thread, but manipulating returned `Future` object on main thread. Please see my re-written answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please note this statement in the description for [getAuthToken](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/accounts/AccountManager.html#getAuthToken%28android.accounts.Account,%20java.lang.String,%20boolean,%20android.accounts.AccountManagerCallback%3Candroid.os.Bundle%3E,%20android.os.Handler%29) method you are using:

> This method may be called from any thread, but the returned
>   AccountManagerFuture must not be used on the main thread.

You obviously violate this, as your `MyAccount#getAuthToken()` is accessing the `Future` on the main thread : `Bundle result = future.getResult();`

I assume that is why you get the exception.

Hope that helps.

Comment: yes, you should call manager.getAuthToken(...); in a separate thread, AsyncTask is fine.

Comment: well, actually according to [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/accounts/AccountManager.html#blockingGetAuthToken%28android.accounts.Account,%20java.lang.String,%20boolean%29) it may not be true that you need a separate thread for `getAuthToken`. Let me check

Comment: I will try to wrap the `MyAccount` functionality into a separate asynctask that gets called from `createTask` and will post back my progress. thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
        Thread CrearEventoHilo = new Thread(){
            public void run(){
                //do something that retrun "Calling this from your main thread can lead to deadlock"
            }
        };
        CrearEventoHilo.start();
        CrearEventoHilo.interrupt();
```

Comment: Adding some explanation to your code will make you answer a lot more useful to future searchers.